# sync multiple ipads to one computer

Tags: data-synchronization, ipad

The NPO I work for has been given 20 ipads for students to use in the classroom. To simplify things I was wanting to set it up so that all ipads could sync to the same PC.

Is this a legal issue with syncing purchased apps to more than one ipad? Would I need to purchase apps x 20? (Music won't be used on these)

Does iTunes have anything built into it to help with this? I'm thinking this has to come up often. Schools purchase iOS devices and want them to be identical.

Any other issues I should know/think about?

Thank you.

Comment: Although this is technically on-topic since it relates to connecting the iPad to a computer, it would be a much better fit for [Ask Different](http://askdifferent.com), the Apple Stack Exchange site. If you would like me to migrate it there, please flag it for moderator attention saying so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Thiago that this shouldn't be a legal issue.  If you have 20 iPads and want to sync them all to one computer, you might want to consider looking into getting a cart or cabinet that syncs and charges all of them automatically.  If you're interested there's more info available at [www.ipadcart.info](http://ipadcart.info)

Comment: Thanks. We went with this cart so you get the check. Just have to wait for them to go on sale.

Answer (score 4):

There are no legal issues in syncing purchased apps to more than one iPad as long as **you** are the owner, which in this case is the school. All you will need to do is to verify in each iPad your iTunes account so that you can sync the apps to each iPad. It has to be same account on all the iPads.

Comment: OK, but now that they are all on the school iTunes account, will a student who has one of these things be able to BUY things from iTunes charging it to the school account?

Comment: Unless you give them the password, no. You should also use the built-in **Restrictions** to further lock it down and disable access, if that's what you want of course.

Answer (score 1):

Thiago and SKL are right - there is no legal problem in purchasing an app once and syncing it on all of your iPads.

There is one app, that should be helpful - [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL851). It will help you deploy and manage your configuration across devices. Also a great resource is the [iOS enterprise](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/) support page - it's full of documentation, that should be useful in your scenario.